# C++/WinRT VISX in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, c++-winrt

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CppWinRTTeam.cppwinrt101804264

This page is only available for VS2019 and 2021.
I would like to use it for past projects created in VS2017, where can I download VSIX the 2017 compatible version?

Comment: So have you downloaded this VISX and did it work in Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: Seems to be the result of a [recent change](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/pull/968), that dropped support for VS2017. While you should be fine to open projects created in VS2017 in VS2019 (and up, hopefully), it's still an unfortunate change.

Comment: thx. It looks like there's been a change.
I will create the project in VS2019 and set the platform toolset to VS2017(v141) and open that project in VS2017.